# For each of the following pairs of functions f(n) and g(n), either f(n) = O(g(n)) or g(n) = O(f(n)), but not both. Determine which is the case

Tags: algorithm, big-o, logarithm

## there is 2 functions: f(n) = n + log n and g(n) = n√n

#### if f(n) = O(g(n)):

n + log n <= C * n√n

#### else if g(n) = O(f(n)):

n√n <= C(n + log n)

stuck to prove that

Comment: try to prove that n*sqrt(n) grows faster than both n and log n.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove

```
n + log(n) <= C*n*sqrt(n)
```

divide by `n` to get

```
1 + log(n)/n <= C*sqrt(n)
```

As `log(n)/n` goes towards zero when `n` goes towards infinity, you get

```
1 <= C*sqrt(n) for n -> infinity
```

which is true.